# Using Gibbs sample to find expectation without nuisance parameter

Tags: statistics, bayesian, sampling, parameter-estimation

Suppose posterior of $P(\theta,\delta|x,y)$ is given.
Gibbs sample is construct as follow

- Start with arbitrary $\theta^{(0)},\delta^{(0)}$ such that $P(\theta^{(0)},\delta^{(0)}|x,y) >0$
- At $t$ iteration , sample each $\theta^{(t)}$ from distribution $P(\theta^{(t)}|\delta^{(t-1)},x,y)$ and $\delta$ from $P(\delta^{(t)}|\theta^{(t)},x,y)$
- Sample of $((\theta^{(m)},\delta^{(m)}),(\theta^{(m+1)},\delta^{(m+1)}),...)$ is taken after burn in.

How can I estimate the $E(\delta|x,y)$ ? noted the expected is with respect to pdf of $P(\delta|x,y)=\int_{\theta}P(\theta,\delta|x,y)d\theta $.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Just use $1/(T - m + 1) \sum_{t=m}^T \delta^{(t)}$ as your estimate for $\mathbb{E}(\delta \mid x, y)$. The sample $\delta^{(m)}, \delta^{(m+1)}, \dots$ is a sample from the marginal distribution $P(\delta \mid x, y)$.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125570/marginalising-over-standard-deviation-of-normal-to-get-the-posterior-on-mean/125574#125574 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134027/marginal-conditional-distribution-from-mcmc-output